# prestashop changing product picture on mouse over on main page

Tags: javascript, prestashop

I am trying to make js function, that will change main product picture on main page, but I don't understand the way the images for each product are sorted in folders. Somewhere I found that it is numberofcategory/numberofproduct/numberofimage, but I think it really doesn't work that way. I already found out how I can incriminate each of this number to get next image, but how can I found out which picture is last one of that product, so I don't jump to another product image.

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Look online for ' Addhomefeatured Module ', it does what you require.

http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/294730-affichage-bugg%C3%A9-des-produits-phares-selon-la-longueur-du-titre/

Good luck.